# How to render FK value in foreach Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

In my application, there are two tables **tickets** and **flights** I want to loops the data from table flights that column **route** have the same values with tickets table (In table tickets also have route column)

Table: **tickets**

- id
- route
- name
- depart_city_id
- arrived_city_id

Table: **flights**

- id
- route
- number
- airline_id (FK)
- seat_type (FK)

if I query like this

```
$ticket_flights = DB::table('tickets') ->leftJoin('flights', 'flights.route', '=', 'tickets.route')->orderBy('price', 'asc')->get();
```

I am able to get the loop I want, but can't render FK value like airline_id or seat_type

but if I do the query like this

```
 $ticket_flights = Flight::with('airline')->get();
```

I am able to render FK but will get all the data from flights table even don't have the same route with tickets table

This is my for loop

```
@foreach ($ticket_flights as $flight)
  <tr>
     <td class="text-center">
          <img src="{{$flight->airline->logo }}" class="logo-airline">
     </td>
      <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($flight->ticketing_period_start)) }} - {{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($flight->ticketing_period_end)) }}</td>
      <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($flight->ticketing_period_start)) }} - {{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($flight->ticketing_period_end)) }}</td>
      <td>{{ $flight->travel_class->name }}</td>
      <td class="text-right">{{$flight->price }}THB</td>
      <td class="text-center">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">View</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Book</a>
      </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

I already make a relationship in the Flight model and able FK in the single page

```
public function airline()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Airline');
}

public function travel_class()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TravelClass');
}
```

Comment: from your first query you can get airline_id and seat_type ryt ? if tickets and fligths has same same route then you will get it ryt ?